# Minimize a function in a given interval with scipy.optimize.brute

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to minimize a function in a given interval; in my case the interval is `[-pi/2, pi/2]`.

Here is what I wrote in my script:

```
ranges = slice(-pi/2, pi/2, pi/200)
res = optimize.brute(g, (ranges,))
```

with

```
def g(x):
    # z and a are global
    (-(z+1) * (((a/4) * (3*cos(x/3) + cos(3*x/2)) +
                (b/4) * (-3*sin(x/2)-3*sin(3*x/2)))**2 +
               ((a/4‌​) * (sin(x/3) + sin(3*x/2)) + (b/4)*
                (cos(x/2) + 3*cos(3*x/2)))**2) + 4*(c*cos(x/2))**2)
```

and the result `res` is

```
array([-3.14159265])
```

The problem I encounter while plotting my solutions is that some of the solutions of the minimization are outside the interval `[-pi/2, pi/2]`. Any help?

Comment: Do you have a practical example of `g` when the solution exceeds the interval? And the value of the results?

Comment: To answer my own comment, looks like `def g(x): return sin(0.5*x)` already fits the bill.

Comment: here is my function : -(z+1)*(((a/4)*(3*cos(x/3)+cos(3*x/2))+(b/4)*(-3*sin(x/2)-3*sin(3*x/2)))**2+((a/4)*(sin(x/3)+sin(3*x/2))+(b/4)*(cos(x/2)+3*cos(3*x/2)))**2)+4*(c*cos(x/2))**2

Comment: Eh..., mind if I stick to my `sin(0.5*x)` example? ;-).

Comment: I've updated your question with the input and output you've given. It's clearer than putting it in the comments, but I assume you don't have enough reputation to edit the question yourself yet.

Answer (score 14):

The "problem" is with the default "finishing function": `brute` has the option of supplying a finishing minimization function. It does this so that the brute force method can be used as a first guess, and then the result can be "polished" using a better minimization function.

If this function is set to None, nothing happens, which is likely what you want here. Unfortunately in this case, the default is set to `fmin`, which is the downhill simplex (Nelder-Mead) method, and this will simply ignore any range/grid specification. Thus, for a function like `sin(0.5 * x)`, it will start at the lowest point that the `brute` function found (`-pi/2`) and continue from there, finding `-pi` to be the (closest-by) global minimum.

The solution is simple:

```
res = optimize.brute(g, (ranges,), finish=None)
```

will give what you want.

Mandatory link to the [scipy.optimize.brute documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html).

Comment: +1. This is not the first time someone has been surprised by the default behavior of `brute`, where `finish=fmin`: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1613

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks. I was about to look for this (I don't use `brute`, so I was surprised myself seeing this). It is unfortunate that the apparent reason for not having `finish=None` as a default is backwards compability. With no 1.0 release yet, it could be changed (but yes, lots of scientists would be surprised or wouldn't even notice incorrect results, since I don't expect that the majority of scipy users carefully reads the release notes between versions).

Comment: There's no way to put bounds on fmin and make them match by default?

Answer (score 0):

You can just write your objective function to return np.inf if the parameter it is passed is outside your desired range.  So, for example:

```
def g(x, x_limit):

if x > x_limit:
    return np.inf
else:
    return (-(z+1) * (((a/4) * (3*cos(x/3) + cos(3*x/2)) +
           (b/4) * (-3*sin(x/2)-3*sin(3*x/2)))**2 +
           ((a/4‌​) * (sin(x/3) + sin(3*x/2)) + (b/4)*
           (cos(x/2) + 3*cos(3*x/2)))**2) + 4*(c*cos(x/2))**2)
```